# NSLayoutConstraint margin zero instead of sixteen

Tags: ios, swift3, nslayoutconstraint

I'm building a UICollectionViewCell interface by code. Everything works fine, except the right constraint. When I run the app the title label has a zero margin from the right. Here is my code

```
let titleLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

func setupViews() {
    addSubview(titleLabel)

    // titleLabel
    // top constraint
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 16))
    // left constraint
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))
    // right constraint
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 16))
    // height constraint
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0, constant: 20))
}
```

I'm thinking it has something to do with `toItem: self`, because `self` is the `uilabel` and I want to related it the `UICollectionViewCell`

Comment: Is the cell size loaded before adding subviews? If no, load the cell, then run setupViews and then run self.setNeedsDisplay(), self.layoutIfNeeded(). If yes you can try running the functions above also.

Comment: What happens if you use `-16` for the right constraint constant?

Comment: @vacawama it works! How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the order of your items in your constraint.  You are currently saying the label is 16 past the right edge of its superview.  You can either switch the `item` and `toItem` in your right constraint, or use `-16` as your constant.

So either this:

```
addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: titleLabel, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 16))
```

or this:

```
addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: -16))
```

will work.